# Allow undefined function calls in TypeScript to test for JavaScript environments

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, typescript

I'm building a small TypeScript framework, for which I also want to ensure JavaScript compatibility. I have a class interface like this:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(name : string, id : number);
}
```

Since this function might be called also from plain JavaScript, I also have some sanity check to ensure that the parameters actually have the correct types.

So far, so good. For this function I also have unit-tests written in TypeScript. What I want now is to have a unit-test that checks whether this function throws an exception when supplied with the wrong parameter types. For example:

```
new Foo(3) // throws an exception
// Undefined overload in TS
// But should be testable in TS for JS-compatibility
```

The problem now is, that when compiling such a unit-test it will throw an error, correctly stating that the function I'm trying to call doesn't exist. Meaning I can't compile my TypeScript unit-test.

The best workaround I have so far is to define these types of unit-tests as JavaScript tests and not TypeScript tests. But I'd rather group these tests together with all other tests for the class Foo, instead of splitting them, by Type- and JavaScript.

So, I'm looking for a way to tell the compiler that within the scope of my unit-test it's ok to call this undefined function, so I can test it. Or maybe define the signature for the scope of the test. Does anybody know if that's possible?

Thanks!

Pedro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks a bit nasty, but you can tell the compiler to treat `Foo` as `any`:

```
var a = new (<any>Foo)(3);
```

The `<any>` type assertion is the important bit.

Comment: Thanks! that's definitely a better workaround than what I had though of until now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can override what Typescript is thinking about variable type using cast syntax:

```
var a = new Foo(<string> 42, <number> "not a number")
```

in this case you will get compile time error if you change the constructor signature even without running the test.